# Thrift async response is crossed with wrong service method

Tags: python, thrift

I came across with strange issue while using Thrift server in TThreadedServer mode. My test client makes parallel calls (100 calls) to the server. Say two methods in my thrift service 
are `load_account()`  and `getRequestQueueCoun()`. These methods have async calls with `send_load_account and recv_load_account()`. `send_getRequestQueueCoun()` and `recv_getRequestQueueCoun()`.

The problem I am facing is response of `send_getRequestQueueCoun()` call is being captured in `recv_load_account()`.

I found the response in the following line

```
def recv_load_account(self, ):
(fname, mtype, rseqid) = self._iprot.readMessageBegin()  # here fname is the other method.
```

Server initialization Code -

```
handler =   SyncServiceHandler(settings.SERVER_NAME,settings.SERVER_LISTEN_IP,settings.SERVER_LISTEN_PORT,isDispatcher)
transport = TSocket.TServerSocket(settings.SERVER_LISTEN_IP, settings.SERVER_LISTEN_PORT)
processor = SyncService.Processor(handler)
tfactory = TTransport.TBufferedTransportFactory()
pfactory = TBinaryProtocol.TBinaryProtocolFactory()
server = TServer.TThreadedServer(processor, transport, tfactory, pfactory)
```

**I am running two thrift instance in localhost on different ports.**

I am using **Thrift with Python 2.7.**

I tried my best to quickly draft my problem. If it's still not clear, let me know if I can elaborate it.

Thanks in Advance.
Panakj